# Intent error when pressing back button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio

I have 3 activities , A --> B --> C
Activity A has a listview , Activity B has a child listview , C has a detail for Activity B listview item

Categories Activity --> Stories Activity --> StoryDetailActivity

Everything is Ok untill i click back button on the StoryDetailActivity the app crashes , here is the logcat

> 10-28 09:35:48.125 5607-5607/com.example.zack.stories E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.zack.stories.activities.StoriesActivity.onCreate(StoriesActivity.java:42)

Here is Line 42

```
Categories category=getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(EXTRA_CAT);
```

Here is The storyActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_newslist);
    final ListView mlist=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lsv_cat_item);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     Categories category=getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(EXTRA_CAT);


    mAdapter = new StoryListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),0);

    RestAdapter restAdapter=new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(getString(R.string.categories_feed)).build();
    final CategoriesApiInterface categoriesApiInterface=restAdapter.create(CategoriesApiInterface.class);
    categoriesApiInterface.getStreams2(category.getCat_id(), new Callback<List<Stories>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(List<Stories> stories, Response response) {
            if (stories == null || stories.isEmpty()) {
                return;}

            for(Stories stories1 : stories){
                mAdapter.add(stories1);

            }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mlist.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.e("Stories", "Retrofit error " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });


mlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), StoryDetailActivity.class );
        intent.putExtra(StoryDetailActivity.EXTRA_STORY, mAdapter.getItem(position));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});


}
```

And StorydetailActicity

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_story_detail);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById( R.id.tool_bar );
    setSupportActionBar( toolbar );
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled( true );

    Stories story=getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(EXTRA_STORY);

    TextView story_title = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.story_title );
    TextView story_body = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.story_body );

    story_title.setText( story.getStory_title() );
    story_body.setText(story.getStory_body());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the details you provided and stacktrace, it seems like, your `StoriesActivity` is destroyed when you are starting `StoryDetailsActivity`. May be low memory from OS.

So whenever you are pressing `Back Button` on `StoryDetailsActivity` it is going to create `StoriesActivity` again and in that activity **intent has no value for** `EXTRA_CAT`.

I suggest to use `startActivityForResult()` in `StoriesActivity` when you call startActivity for `StoryDetailsActivity` if you want to navigate back on same screen.

And also look at your launch mode in Activity tag in manifest file if they are responsible for recreating activity (mostly not).

Comment: Thank you for responding , but how to do that ,

Comment: Look at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html . In your case just don't send any result from previous activity.

Comment: i added startActivityForResult in storiesActivity , and  onActivityResult on storiesDetailactivity , but the same error